# How to write a string array with a Utf8JsonWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, system.text.json

I am doing some tests and would like to manually write a JSON object to file using the `Utf8JsonWriter` rather than the `JsonSerializer`.

I have the following code:

```
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WriteStartObject("InformationObject");
writer.WriteString("Name", "Info Name");
writer.WriteString("Details", "Info Details");
writer.WriteStartArray("Tags");
```

In the `Tags` array property I would like to write an array of strings, however if I try to use `WriteString` or any other method after the `WriteStartArray` call, the code fails at runtime.

There is no "WriteArrayContents" method or anything like that, so I am curious what method you're meant to call after `WriteStartArray` to actually write the array contents?

Am I just misunderstanding the way JSON works or is there something I've missed with the MS API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call [`WriteStringValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writestringvalue?view=netcore-3.1) to write a string value into an array:

> Writes a string text value (as a JSON string) **as an element of a JSON array**.

And, more generally, you need to use one of the [`Write*Value()` methods of `Utf8JsonWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter?view=netcore-3.1#methods) (such as [`WriteBooleanValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writebooleanvalue?view=netcore-3.1) or [`WriteNumberValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writenumbervalue?view=netcore-3.1)) to write an array element of the appropriate type.

Thus your `Write()` method should look like:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, InformationObject value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WriteStartObject("InformationObject");
    writer.WriteString("Name", "Info Name");
    writer.WriteString("Details", "Info Details");
    writer.WriteStartArray("Tags");     

    // Write some dummy values here
    writer.WriteStringValue("value1");
    writer.WriteStringValue("value2");

    writer.WriteEndArray();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JGyY7M).

Comment: Your fiddle never uses the method Write

Comment: The fiddle adds the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` and then serializes the object, which causes the converter's `Write()` method to get called.